# How do I change some content that is not in a descendant element?

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to modify the content in an XML file. If the pattern is in a tag, then it should not get converted. All other occurances of that pattern in the rest of the file should get converted.

Input:

```
<abc>A change to a 1207.52 good of  <link>subheading 1207.91</link> from 
within that subheading or any 2004.92 other chapter.</abc>
```

Here, I am planning to convert `\d{4}\.\d{2}` to `<adi>\d{4}\.\d{2}</adi>`. But the pattern within in the `<link>` tag is also getting modified.

Expected Output:

```
<abc>A change to a <adi>1207.52</adi> good of  <link>subheading 1207.91</link> from 
within that subheading or any <adi>2004.92</adi> other chapter.</abc>
```

Can any of you please help in solving this issue?

Comment: Isn't `1207.52` also inside a tag?

Comment: @mob In this case, I think he is referring to any tags between the main tag `abc`

Comment: I don't believe it can be done with a single regex substitution.

Comment: @mob It may or may not be inside the tag.

Comment: @hwnd The regex should modify the pattern found anywhere except within the <link> .. </link> tag. In otherwords, the logic should ignore the text within the <link> tags.

Answer (score 0):

@Adithya Kiran : Slurp the input file content into a variable $document and then do the below-

```
$document =~ s/(\d{4}\.\d{2})(?!(?:(?!<\/link>|<link>).)*<\/link>)/<adi>$1<\/adi>/isg;
```